PowerShell Script for renaming multiple files with a common phrase in multiple folders
I have files within folders on a Windows 10 system that are template files. These files are all named xxxxxx[Vendor Name]. Is there a PowerShell script i can write that can search for files with "vendor name" as specific text and replace it with the name of the folder, which in each case is the vendor's name? This would save hours of renaming.
Minimal scripting knowledge

The short answer is "yes". But you probably want an actual script. Is "xxxxxxx" a static string or a pattern you can match (like all numerals, or a fixed six characters) so you can infer the vendor name or do you have a list of vendor names to search for?

I should've provided more clarity. Here is how the files are set up:
Folder Name is Company ABC
Files within are ExcelDocName[Vendor Name] and WordDocName[Vendor Name].
I am looking to run something that will update the [Vendor Name] section to the appropriate vendor. Since these are in each vendor's folder already, I figured the script would take the Company ABC and replace [Vendor Name] in each with Company ABC. Goal would be ExcelDocName[Company ABC] and WordDocName[CompanyABC]. This would then be repeatable for all the vendor folders that are within the master folder.

You should clarify what operating system and/or shell you use.

Windows 10/Powershell

Read the details for for /?.  This will give you enough information to write such a script.  It allows for string replacement, and running commands (such as ren).
